# get String from EditText

Tags: android, if-statement, android-edittext

```
login.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if( username_text.getText().toString() == "admin" &&
                    pass_text.getText().toString() == "password"){

                startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVITY_CREATE);

            }else{
                Toast.makeText(gps_gui.this, "Your username or password is not correct! Please, insert again",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                clearEditText();
            }
        }

    });
```

I'm try to check it, I found it not go to if condition.

Comment: You should accept any correct answers to your previous questions. You can just click the check mark beside an answer to mark it as accepted.

Comment: I did pretty much this same exact test -- even using "admin" and "password" as the values. Nice! :) Thanks for asking this question!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

When using java, you must compare Strings using the String.equals(String) method.  The == comparison checks to see if the String object values are equal, which undoubtedly they are not.  Try to change you example to :

```
"admin".equals(username_text.getText().toString()) &&"password".equals(pass_text.getText().toString())
```

Its also smart to put the static string first, in case the string value of the value being checked is null.

Comment: It is casesensitive.  As @msumaithri mentioned, you can use equalsIgnoreCase as an alternative (though I wouldn't recommend you do for passwords and usernames)

Comment: just adding for naive like me if you add ansi value of admin and ansi value of password it turns out to be different so...

Answer (score 3):

Use String class's equals() method to compare Strings. The following links would give you more details.

[About equals(Object yourObj) method (CASE sensitive)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29)

equalsIgnoreCase(String yourStringObject) can be used, if you want it to be not case sensitive!